# Preventing what was/were previously copied on to my clipboard from appearing on R Console when using R

Tags: r, clipboard-interaction, tinn-r

I am having some problems with my clipboard contents when using R. When I run my scripts/commands in tinn-r, very often I would get something that I had ran earlier pasted onto my R Console instead of the command that I have just selected.

To get over this, I would go to my clipboard and delete its content(text/syntax). However, the same text/syntax that I had just deleted would re-appear on my clipboard and would again appear on my R Console when trying to run a different syntax from my tinn-r.

Answer (score 1):

Good luck.  Tinn-R seems to be a particularly buggy way of interacting with R.  Though it takes some effort to set up, the StatET plugin interface from Eclipse has been working way better for me than Tinn-R ever did.

Comment: ... and these days I much rather use RStudio than StatET.